# How to create a "Command" like event when a DataGridCell is being edited

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datagridcell

In my program I have a `DataGrid` with 4 different columns. I would like to make it so that, in one of the columns, when a cell is selected for editing, I am able to change the content of that cell programmatically. For example, on edit, the current `string` value in the selected cell might change to `"selected"`. I've looked through the `DataGridCell` class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcell(v=vs.110).aspx), and haven't really found anything that would detect an edit to a cell. It would be nice if there was like some "cellClick" event for each `DataGridTextColumn` in xaml. How do I achieve this type of handler?

The xaml of my `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SysModel.SystemCollection}" MinColumnWidth="50" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyleWithAlternation}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterCellStyle}"
          RowHeaderWidth="0" AlternationCount="2" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" SelectionUnit="Cell" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="471" Name="dataGrid1" Width="468" Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="17">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource cart}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding cartNum}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource ipAddress}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding ipAddress}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource portNumber}" Width="70" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding PortNumber}" />
        <!-- **This is the column that contains the cells I want to have this event for** -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource configuration}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding Configuration}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#726AA5" x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />
        </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataGridCell` fires `Selected` event when it is selected. I presume Before it is being edited by user, it should be selected.

Source: [DataGridCell Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcell_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: To convert an event to a command you can use `EventToCommand` from MVVM Light. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx (Figure 9)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. There is no mention about a command in the question, except in the title, so I ignored it. But yes, @Aybe suggested correctly to use EventToCommand if there really is intent to bind to a ICommand implementation.